# Java Setting up a Simple Proxy

Tags: java

I use a vpn so I need a proxy to make a REST post on POSTMAN. So I setup a Proxy IP and port and it works...

But in Java I get connection timeout even tho I setup the proxy programally.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",ip);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort",port);
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Specify what REST library you are using. It could be it is ignoring the `http.proxyHost` System properties and has its own.

Comment: it's just HttpURLConnection

Comment: The protocol is HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: It's HTTPS......

Comment: So it needs to be `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

Comment: @jbx thanks that's probably that

Comment: OK. Added a more formal answer. Accept it if it solved the problem so that other people will be able to use it if they search for the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has different properties for http and https proxy settings, since you might want to use a different proxy for each.

In this case you need to set `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort`.

Full details of the Networking Properties Java supports are listed here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html